# JS runtime errors in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling

I have a basic Express app which has a few routes.

One is as such:

```js
router.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
  let audioFile = req.files.audioFile;

  const file = __dirname + '/../' + req.body.uploadLocation + audioFile.name;

  mp3.mv(file, function(err) {  // <--- HERE
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }

    res.send('File uploaded!');
  });
});
```

Now, if you would try to upload a file to this route you would get a `500` and that's it. The highlighted line is a result of me changing variable name. Is there any way to get it so that it prints out the actual error? I am tripped up by this so often and it would make it an awful lot quicker if the terminal output just told me the normal JS error like it does on the browser or when I'm running node normally.

Comment: Make it so that "what" prints out the actual error?  Server or client display?  Usually, you would log the internal error object to your server console with `console.log(err)` so you can see the exact error there.  A regular error object is not really set up to send to the end-user.

Comment: I'm talking about the terminal output where you see the Express requests go in and out. I have no `err` to log since in my example it is a syntax error. I'm not talking about an error from making a db request or something.

Comment: Then you need a `try/catch` in the proper scope to catch that and log it.  In an asynchronous event handler (which an Express route handler is), it will not necessarily get logged automatically.  This is a general advantage of using promises instead of plain callbacks for all asynchronous operations as you will either catch the errors from promises yourself (and they automatically catch more things) or they will get logged for you as an uncaught rejection (which is a bug because you should never have an uncaught rejection in your code).

Comment: Yeah, I realised that I can do that, but I don't really want to have to do that with every single route I'm developing. Surely there's a better way!

Comment: Read this: [Error Handling in Express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html).

Comment: Thanks, that gave me the answer alright :peace:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Express there is middleware to handle errors. In the a base setup of express you'll find:

```js
// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  ...
  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.json({ error: err });
});
```

Just add a `console.error` there:

```js
// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack); // <- HERE
  ...
  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.json({ error: err });
});
```